# observe bookmark added/updated/removed in android browser

Tags: android, browser, bookmarks, contentobserver

I am using Content-Observer to observe the Android-Boroswers browser.db which stores information about both history & bookmarks. My requirement is that i want to get notified only if a BOOKMARK is added/updated/removed & update my bookmarks list. But my listener gets fired even if a new page loads into the browser ( because this comes under history). Any way to resolve this ? or to observe changes for a single column. 
I dont want to unnecesary update my list on every event fired. 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any way to resolve this ?

Add to your `WHERE` clause a check to see if the [`BOOKMARK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.BookmarkColumns.html#BOOKMARK) column is `1`.

Comment: yes CommonsWare, i can put this check when i get the notification. I just want to avoid unnecessary notifications. I just want to observe Bookmark add/update/delete events, no history updates.

Comment: @Ash: "i can put this check when i get the notification." -- actually, that's not what I meant, but it dawns on me now that what I meant isn't actually possible. When you query the `Bookmarks` content provider, you can add a `WHERE` clause to restrict the output to bookmarks. However, that's only for queries. When you register a content observer, you can only specify a `Uri`. My apologies for my confusion.